# React native debug performance issues

Tags: react-native

I understand that running the app as debug while having some `console.log`s here and there will most definitely slow down its performance, but it sometimes become obnoxiously really slow... It takes me around 5-10 minutes to navigate between scenes without fetching any data from an API.

Enabling the Perf Monitor usually gives me this result when it suddenly starts running really slow:

```
========================
| UI: 59.0 FPS         | // normal fps
| 149 dropped so far   | // sometimes goes up to 220+
| 0 tuters (4+) so far | // sometimes goes up to 14+
| JS: 59.0 FPS         | // normal fps
========================
```

Is this a normal behavior? Am I really forced to wait 5 minutes+ while debugging?

Edit: I am using Android not iOS

Comment: You didn't specify but if is iOS we're talking about make sure Debug > Slow Animations is not checked.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am in Android not iOS

Answer (score 0):

It may be late to answer but I think in debugging mode Scene transitions are very slow. It's performance even get worse when you log something out.
For faster response and actual Frame history you can uncheck JS Dev Mode from the settings.